# Make elements sortable through different levels and change the elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I need to sort some elements of this HTML-construct:

```
<div class="main">
<section class="box_1">
    <div class="box_delete"></div>
    <header class="trigger"><h2 contenteditable="true">TITLE</h2></header>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="editable">
            <p>Level1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box_2">
            <div class="box_delete"></div>
            <div class="box_rand"></div>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="editable">
                    <p>Level2</p>
                </div>
                <div class="box_3">
                    <div class="box_delete"></div>
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="editable">
                            <p>Level3-1</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="box_3">
                    <div class="box_delete"></div>
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="editable">
                            <p>Level3-2</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>                  
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
</div>
```

So I'm using JQuery UI. For example like this:

```
$(".main").sortable({
    opacity: 0.5,
    items: '.box_1'
});
$(".box_1").sortable({
    opacity: 0.5,
    items: '.box_2'
});
$(".box_2").sortable({
    opacity: 0.5,
    items: '.box_3'
});
```

I got some problems with that:

1. The .content-container contains an editor element, that means the content is editable. Sortable() leads to the problem, that I cannot select Text in the editor as the element will be catched to sort it.
2. This is the main problem: I would like to take a box_3 element out of the box_2-container to put it in a box_1-container. Then it should get a box_2-class/element. The same thing if I want to put a box_3 or box_2 element out of the section -> it should get a box_1-element. Is this possible?

**Update:**

I solved 1.: I put the handler on ".box_delete". Then ".editable" is editable!

Partly solved 2.: With `connectWith` I can get a box to another level. With `stop: function( event, ui ) {}` I can start a function wich should check for the parent class to get the new level --> adjust to a correct box-structure: e.g. I put a box_2-element to the main-class --> it should become a box_1 element with the structure of a box_1

**JSFIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/xssLmrvb/4/

Comment: I'm not sure about your issue but try it: http://mjsarfatti.com/sandbox/nestedSortable/

Comment: I don't know how to adapt it to my example (see jsfiddle). First all Elements (box_1, box_2, box_3) should bee sortable with each other and as a second task, the sorted box should become the correct class.

Comment: the html structure is be able to be changed?

Comment: unfortunatly not. Which changes have to be done?

Comment: Can you update the jsfiddle with the changes you mentioned in the update?

Comment: What's supposed to be 'editable' ? Why not use an input for an editable area? Not sure I'm understanding how a paragraph should be editable. Can you clarify what you want this to do please?

Comment: *"box_3 or box_2 element out of the section -> it should get a box_1-element"* - it should just get the class or become a `<section>` element..?

Comment: get the class and become a section element. It should completly become a 'real' section box_1 element. If you put a box_2 element with a inner box_3 element out of the section -> box_2 becomes a section-box_1 element and the inner box_3 will become a box_2 element (with a box_2 structure).

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to change the HTML. Just do it like this:

```
$(".box_1").sortable({
    opacity: 0.5,
    items: '.box_2',
    handle: '.box_delete',
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
    connectWith: ".main",
    stop: function( event, ui ) {
        var box = ui.item;
        if(box.parent().attr('class')=="main") {
            var content = $(box).find(".content").html();
            var box_delete = '<div class="box_delete"></div>';
            var header_trigger = '<header class="trigger"><h2>TITLE</h2></header>';
            var box_content = '<div class="content">'+content+'</div>';

            $(box).replaceWith(function () {
                return $('<section class="box_1 ui-sortable"></div>')
                        .append(box_delete)
                        .append(header_trigger)
                        .append(box_content);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

This is a example how a box_2-element will be changed to a real box_1 element.
With that the complete structure (!) will change (not only the class) - as you need it.
Just do the same Thing for the other levels.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so to change the class of the object you could do something like this:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xssLmrvb/9/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="main">
    <section class="box_1 connected">
        <div class="box_delete"></div>
        <header class="trigger">
             <h2 contenteditable="true">TITLE</h2>

        </header>
        <div class="content level1">
            <div class="editable">
                <p>Level1</p>
            </div>
            <div class="box_2 connected">
                <div class="box_delete"></div>
                <div class="box_rand"></div>
                <div class="content level2">
                    <div class="editable">
                        <p>Level2</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box_3">
                        <div class="box_delete"></div>
                        <div class="content">
                            <div class="editable">
                                <p>Level3-1</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box_3">
                        <div class="box_delete"></div>
                        <div class="content">
                            <div class="editable">
                                <p>Level3-2</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
$(".main").sortable({
    opacity: 0.5,
    helper: 'clone',
    items: '.box_1',
    connectWith: '.connected'
});
$(".box_1").sortable({
    opacity: 0.5,
    items: '.box_2',
    helper: 'clone',
    connectWith: '.connected',
    stop: stopfunction
});
$(".box_2").sortable({
    opacity: 0.5,
    items: '.box_3',
    helper: 'clone',
    connectWith: '.connected',
    stop: stopfunction
});

function stopfunction(e, ui){
    var item = ui.item;
    if(item.parent().hasClass('level1')) {
        removeBoxClasses(item);
        item.addClass('box_2');
    }
    else if(item.parent().hasClass('level2')) {
        removeBoxClasses(item);
        item.addClass('box_3');
    }
}

function removeBoxClasses(elem){
    elem.removeClass('box_1').removeClass('box_2').removeClass('box_3');
}
```

I am not sure that this is exactly what you want. But I hope it gives you an idea. Updated answer with KevinAlbs changes.

Comment: I just tried the fiddle: If I take the "Level 3-1"-Box and put it below "Level 1", it should get a box_2 (--> blue) as it is now a child of the box_1

Comment: @user3142695 When I do that in the fiddle provided it does become blue.